# How to obtain transition probability matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, markov-chains

Suppose I have a sequence x= 1,3,3,1,2,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,4,4,4,3,1,2,5,1 and it has five states 1 3 2 4 5. I have to obtain transition probability matrix in MATLAB by this equation, probability= (Number of observation pairs x(t) & x(t+1), with x(t) in state i and x(t+1) in state j)/(Number of observation pairs x(t) & x(t+1), with x(t) in state i and x(t+1) in any one of the states 1......s).
I tried by this code but it giving error

```
x=[1 3 3 1 2 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 5 1]
n = length(x)-1
p = zeros(5,5)
for t = 1:n
if x(t)=x(t+1);
   a(t)=count (x(t)=x(t+1)) % Here i am trying to count how many number of times pair of that states occur in sequence.
   q(t)=sum(x==x(t)) % (Here i am trying to count Number of observation pairs x(t) & x(t+1), with x(t) in state i and x(t+1) in any one of the states 1......s)
end
for i=1:5
p(i, :) = a(t)/q(t)
end
```

Transition probability matrix calculated manually by me as follows

```
                     1      3     2    4     5

                1    0     1/5   2/5  2/5    0

                3    3/4   1/4    0    0     0

                2    1/4   1/4    0    1/4   1/4

                4     0    1/5   2/5   2/5   0

                5     1     0     0     0    0
```

Comment: I think you can figure this out for yourself; you will learn a lot more that way. Fill the p matrix with the number of occurrences of each pair i,j and then divide the rows by the row sums to get the probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been a while, I think it is safe to provide an answer to this now.  There is **no toolbox required** for either approach below. The approach assumes basic knowledge of a [transition probability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix#Definition_and_properties) of a [Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Discrete-time_Markov_chain).

Both approaches use the [`unique()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function to find the statespace. Note that the order is different, e.g. your `[1 3 2 4 5]` vs. my `[1 2 3 4 5]` but that isn't a limiting issue. I've separated getting the transition **counts** from the transition **probabilities** to illustrate some techniques.

---

**Approach 1: Vectorized Approach**
This approach uses the [`unique()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) functions.

```
% MATLAB 2018b
X =[1 3 3 1 2 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 5 1];
[u,~,n] = unique(X);
NumU = length(u);     % Number of Unique Observations
Counts = accumarray([n(1:end-1),n(2:end)],1,[NumU,NumU]);

P = Counts./sum(Counts,2);   % Probability transition matrix
```

*Verification:* You can verify that `sum(sum(Counts)) == length(X)-1` and the rows of `P` sum to one (`sum(P,2)`).

Notice that the counts matrix uses a 1-step offset to count the transitions. The output is a `NumU x NumU` array of the number of transitions in terms of indices as given in the `n`-output from `unique()`.

---

**Approach 2: Single `for` loop**
This is a direct approach that can use any ordering of the statespace (see below).

```
States = unique(X);   % <--- can be anything
                      % e.g. try: States = [1 3 2 4 5];

Counts = zeros(length(States));
for k = 2:length(X)
    Counts(find(X(k-1) == States),find(X(k) == States)) = ...
        Counts(find(X(k-1) == States),find(X(k) == States)) + 1;
end

P = Counts./sum(Counts,2);   % Probability transition matrix
```

Using your statespace ordering: If you use **Approach 2** with `States = [1 3 2 4 5];`, the resulting probability transition matrix, `P`, matches the one you manually calculated.